# How to call class VectorClass_1 from public CustomSeekBar(Context context) in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my scenario, I am trying to call `this.progressAnimate = new VectorClass_1();` from `public CustomSeekBar(Context context)` and `public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` but I am getting error: cannot find symbol this.progressAnimate = new VectorClass_1();. How to resolve it?

```
class CustomSeekBar extends View {
    VectorClass_1 progressAnimate = null;

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.progressAnimate = new VectorClass_1();
   class VectorClass_1 implements Runnable {

    }       
}
```

Comment: `this.mAnimate` is not found in the code

Comment: @ShaluTD I have updated my code.

Comment: @ShaluTD is there any idea?

Comment: please upload full class of customview

Comment: @ShaluTD `VectorClass_1();` this class is not referring, So I am getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see your `customview` class. You should place the `VectorClass_1` class outside the constructor. I think below code will solve your issue:-

```
class CustomSeekBar extends View {
    VectorClass_1 progressAnimate = null;

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.progressAnimate = new VectorClass_1();
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.progressAnimate = new VectorClass_1();
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.progressAnimate = new VectorClass_1();
    }

    static class VectorClass_1 implements Runnable {
        VectorClass_1() {
        }

        public void run() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use `class VectorClass_1` Inside `public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { ... }` because CustomSeekBar I used some logic within run code.

Comment: yes, you can do the operation by creating its instance there . I created its object there

Comment: If you want to do any operation inside VectorClass_1(), you can pass parameters through constructor and do the work

Comment: I have updated the code, Please check it once and let me know the changes.

Comment: class should be outside